# Can't create thread in vala: `GLib.Thread' does not have a default constructor

Tags: multithreading, glib, vala

This sample program does not compile:

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public bool do_work () {
       message ("OTHER THREAD: %p", (void*)Thread.self ) ;
       return false ;
    }

    public void run () {
        Thread<bool> thread1 = new Thread<bool>.try ("queuejobmanager-thread-1", do_work);
        thread1.join () ;
    }
 }       

int main (string[] args) {

    message ("MAIN THREAD: %p", (void*)Thread.self ) ;
    var item = new MyClass () ;
    item.run () ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

The error is:

```
vala-thread.vala:10.36-10.51: error: The name `try' does not exist in the context of `GLib.Thread'
        Thread<bool> thread1 = new Thread<bool>.try ("queuejobmanager-thread-1", do_work);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in [the sample](http://valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.Thread), you have to build using the option **--target-glib 2.32**

The complete build line is:

```
valac <your vala file>  --target-glib 2.32
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a make fill that that you can customize

```
VALAC=valac
EXEC=runMe
VALAFILES=test.vala test2.vala test3.vala
VALAPKGS=
VALAOPTS=--thread --target-glib=2.32

default:
    $(VALAC) $(VALAFILES) -o $(EXEC) $(VALAPKGS) $(VALAOPTS)

run:
    ./$(EXEC)

clean:
    rm -f *.o pp
```

enter your classes that you want to compile in the line

VALA FILES = test.vala

then perform the command in bash;

> make
>
> make run